# Define a C++ class in 2 cpp files?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

Can I **declare** my class in 1 header file and **define** it in 2 separated cpp files ? *(like in C#)*
Main reason is for me to reduce the line count of my class definition in the single file I have now. btw all my headers are "include guarded" + "pragma onced".

**Header:** `"foo.h"`

```
#pragma once

#ifndef FOO_H_2014_04_15_0941
#define FOO_H_2014_04_15_0941

class CFoo
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b);
    int sub(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

**Source:** `"foo.cpp"`

```
#include "stadafx.h"
#include "foo.h"

int CFoo::add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and `"foo2.cpp"`

```
#include "stadafx.h"
#include "foo.h"

int CFoo::sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

When I try I get a compiler error in the second cpp file "cannot open source file stdafx.h" (also "foo.h")

Comment: For the love of all that is holy please DON'T do this. Most C++ devs won't expect this and it becomes a nightmare to maintain. If your class is so huge it needs 2 files then you need to fix up your design, probably you need some more objects.

Comment: @paulm Actually it wasn't my design and it's me now who maintains it. I wanted to separate methods that have very different meaning and are also separated via `private / public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

`stdafx.h` is a precompiled header file. This is a convention of Visual Studio. In order to optimize compilation, often-used headers get put in `stdafx.h`, then you include this file. The catch is you *must* put `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of your source files.

You can either do that, or disable precompiled header usage for this .cpp file. Or your whole project.

Make sure you use include guards in your `foo.h` file as well. Either a series of preprocessor directives as @Theolodis has said, or `#pragma once`.

---

I agree with @paulm: Splitting up your implementation like this is just an indication that your design is flawed. It's very *very* rare that this is the "right" decision. Most likely you should consider breaking up your code into smaller, more manageable components.

Answer (score 2):

In the header, add:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

class CFoo
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b);
    int sub(int a, int b);
}

#endif
```

the problem was that your header file has been included twice in the executable, leading to name conflicts. Otherwise everything is fine, you could even take one `.cpp` file for every method.

Comment: I have include guards.

Comment: @mini-me well, then tenfour 's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use "include guarded" and "pragma onced" in the same header file! Use "include guarded" only!

Secondly, you must be develop on the windows, may be use visual studio. Because you used the precompiled header file: stdafx.h. And you spell ERROR!

Only this!